# can anyone explain arguments of these functions?

Tags: node.js, buffer, fs

I am working with NodeJs and trying to write and read binary files.

I am having headache with NodeJs documentation which did not provide much explanations.

Especially I want to know

```
 fs.writeSync(fd, buffer, offset, length, position)
```

I know  'fd' and 'buffer', but confused with 'offset' and 'position'.

```
fs.readSync(fd, buffer, offset, length, position)
```

I guess this one is the same.

can any one explain to me?
Thanks

Comment: The Node.js File System documentation should have everything you need: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: @Sam. I checked there already. just listed them without explanations and examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `offset` is the starting position where you start to read the input buffer (therefore, `offset` + `length` should be equal or less then buffer's size)
- `position` is the starting position where you start to write the output

The following stupid example will show you how it works:

```
const fs = require('fs')

var fd = fs.openSync("test.txt", "w")

var buf = Buffer.alloc(5, 'abcde')
fs.writeSync(fd, buf, 0, buf.length, 0)
// buffer's elements [0-4] are written to file's position 0
// test.txt holds 'abcde'

buf = Buffer.alloc(5, 'fghij')
fs.writeSync(fd, buf, 2, buf.length - 2, 2)
// buffer's elements [2-4] are written to file's position 2
// test.txt holds 'abhij'
```

Comment: NodeJs should put your example on their documentations. Great example, thanks!